# Is it possible to write function that gets Tabular expression and returns string in KQL?

Tags: kql

Is it possible to write a function that will get Tabular expression as input, and return string?

E.g. if I want a function that will return the name of a datetime column in a schema:

```
let timeCol = (T1:(*)){T1 | getschema
|  ColumnType == "datetime"
tostring(any(ColumnName));
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Here you go (note the `toscalar` function, that transforms a tabular result into a scalar):

```
let timeCol = (T1:(*)){
toscalar(T1
| getschema
| where ColumnType == "datetime"
| project ColumnName
| take 1);
};
print (MyTable | invoke timeCol())
```

Comment: Thank you @Slavik N!

But I need to use this value, if exists, inside a query. Specifically, Given an unknoown query, I want to extend new time column that will be equal to the time column if exists, otherwise be now(). E.g.

`
letExistingTimeCol = timecol(requests | summarise  Count() by name);
requests
| extend newTime - iff(string.isEmpty(timecol), now(), timeCol)
`

Comment: Oh, that's a totally different question from the one you asked originally... Unfortunately, what you asked for in the comment is not possible in a generic case. If you have a few "guesses" to what the column name might be, then you can use column_ifexists(), though.

Comment: Many thanks Slavik! that is exactly what I needed :)